# Why wont Rails save the joiner model? Normal behavior or a bug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

The joiner model is not being saved when I try this (assuming`Account has_many :users, through: :roles` and vice-versa):

```
def new
  @account = current_user.accounts.build
end
def create
  @account = current_user.accounts.build(params[:account])
  @account.save # does not save the joiner model
end
```

That should create @account, and a Role record  where `user_id=current_user.id` and `account_id: @account.id`. Only @account gets saved. There are not records in the Role model. The results are consistent using console.

Replace `current_user.accounts.build` with `current_user.accounts.create` in the `create` action, the joiner (role record) model gets saved. For this reason I don't think this is a validation issue. I'm using Rails 3.2.3.

#### Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
  has_many :accounts, through: :roles
end
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
  has_many :users, through: :roles
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
end
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :accounts
end
```

#### View

```
<%= simple_form_for(@account) do |f| %>      
  <%= render 'account_fields', f: f %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `save!` instead of just `save`? It will throw an error and then you can see if anything obvious has gone wrong, like a validation error.

Comment: I don't think this is a validation issue, though. See my update about using `create` instead of `build`.

Comment: @MrDanA, I just tried, and the account gets created, but it's orphaned (no Role record is saved). Why does using `current_user.accounts.create` instead of `current_user.accounts.build` make such a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6161#issuecomment-5631018

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

**UPDATED:**

```rails
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
  has_many :accounts, through: :roles, :autosave => true
end
```

[You can find more info about autosave here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html).

or using a callback in `User` model

```rails
after_save :save_accounts, :if => lambda { |u| u.accounts } 

def save_accounts 
  self.accounts.save
end
```

Comment: no go. The only way I can get this to work is by using `.create`  instead of `.build`. Now, what I am expecting should work, right? So either my code is buggy, or Rails' code has a bug...?